# Код, по-разному работающий в C++03 и C++11/14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Понятно, что изменение смысла `auto` от одного стандарта к другому приводит к возможности ошибки, или, наоборот, ошибочный из-за `>>` в шаблоне код становится нормальным.

А есть код, который при переходе от стандарта С++03 к С++11 (ну, или 14) меняет свой смысл? Работает и там и там но дает разные результаты?

Или даже в С++17? Короче, от одного какого-то стандарта к другому?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В конце стандарта есть приложение "Совместимость", в котором перечислены все несовместимости с предыдущими стандартами.

[Раздел про совместимость текущего стандарта и С++03](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp03)

Несовместимостей много. Вот первая по списку:

```
#define u8 "abc"
const char* s = u8"def";        // Раньше "abcdef", теперь "def"
```

Comment: Не знал о такой тонкости... - https://ideone.com/LEpycU и https://ideone.com/SW0a5z Но VC++2015 тут явно отстал от жизни, он работает по-старому...

Answer (score 2):

Я не такой талант, чтоб придумать настолько тонкое свое, так что "постою на плечах гигантов" (с) Ньютон :)

В "C++ Templates" Вандевурда и компании есть такой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
template<int I> struct X
{
    static int const c = 2;
};
template<> struct X<0>
{
    typedef int c;
};
template<typename T> struct Y
{
    static int const c = 3;
};
static int const c = 4;
int main()
{
    std::cout << (Y<X<1> >::c >::c >::c) << ' ';
    std::cout << (Y<X< 1>>::c >::c >::c) << '\n';
}
```

Результаты работы в старом и новом стандартах:
https://ideone.com/kQi07Y и https://ideone.com/6l8ckM

Идея понятна?

`Y<X< 1>>::c >::c >::c` - в старом стандарте 1 сдвигаем на глобальную `c`, получаем 0, `Y<X<0>::c>` дает `Y<int>`, ну а `Y<int>::c` - это 3.

В новом стандарте `Y<X<1>>::c` равно 3, дальше сравниваем с глобальной `c`, равной 4, получаем `false`, опять сравниваем с глобальной `c`, получаем `0>4 == false`, выводится 0...