# Включает ли новый стандарт C++ в себя старый?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, стандарт

Вот есть c++11 и c++17, я могу писать в c++17 те вещи, которые можно писать в c++11? То есть новый стандарт включает в себя старый?

Comment: только в обратную сторону не работает :)

Comment: Пробегал тут такой вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732730/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-c03-%d0%b8-c11-14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Каждый стандарт С++ "включает" в себя предыдущие стандарты, т.е. в общем и целом обратно совместим с предыдущими стандартами. Но при этом могут иметь место несовместимости ("breaking changes"). Например сужающие преобразования были разрешены в `{}` инициализаторах в С++98/С++03, но запрещены в С++11. Также, каждый новый стандарт может окончательно удалять из языка те возможности, которые были признаны устаревшими/неприемлемыми ("deprecated") в предыдущих стандартах.

Comment: *окончательно удалять из языка те возможности, которые были признаны deprecated в предыдущих стандартах* - по-моему, `auto` было исключением, миновавшим стадию *deprecated* :)

Comment: Тут надо спросить, а сколько людей знает о той другой стороне auto, сколько компиляторов нормально относились. Так что формально он и был deprecated много-много лет.

Comment: Что за deprecated мы тут по русски пишем.

Comment: @Cerbo "не рекомендованный к использованию" длинновато :)

Comment: @KoVadim Вот как раз он был в этом статусе *фактически*, но не *формально*. Формально его никто таковым не объявлял..

Comment: @Harry,@AnT В контексте стандартизации наверно "отмененный" лучше подходит.

Comment: @Harry, учитывая, что о нем почти никто не знал, никто в обычных книжках не писал, он был и формально, и фактически.

Comment: @Cerbo, deprecated это именно «не рекомендованный к использованию». Его никто не отменял, просто стандарт рекомендует прекратить его использование, т.к. в любом будущем стандарте он (функционал) может быть удалён.

Comment: @KoVadim Не хочется на ровном месте разводить дискуссию об отличии *de facto* от *de jure*, так что останемся каждый при своем мнении :)

Comment: Коллеги, а что, разве auto объявлен deprecated?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, речь идёт о старом значение `auto`, унаследованного от C. Но оно удалено, а не deprecated.